# How to subtract two input text and if negative return 0 in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I subtract two input text and put it another input text

Here's what I tried but not working:

**JQUERY :**

```
$(".num3").on("keyup", function() {
 var $this = $(this).parent().parent();

    $this.find('.num1').val($this.find('.num3').val() - $this.find('.num2').val())

});
```

**PHP/HTML:**

```
<input type='text' name='num2' class='num2' value='". number_format((float)$try, 2, '.',''))."' autocomplete='off' readonly  >
<input type='text' name='num3' class='num3' autocomplete='off'>
<input type='text' name='num1' class='num1' readonly>
```

Comment: What is not working, have you checked the values of the individual variables?

Comment: The problem is there is no checkbox. I just want to see the subtraction sum of class.num2 and class.num3 in class.num1 when the amount is keyup in class.num3

Comment: is it a question about `java`?

Comment: Isn't jquery a java? I'm sorry i'm kind of a newbie

Comment: no, jQuery and Java are separate

Comment: @mrid okay thanks for clarifying

Comment: @MonPadi check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript

Comment: Why 3 different classes? You usually would only give the elements different classes if you want different visual appearance. Either identiify your input elements by unique `id="...."` tag; or if you already have a unique `name` attribute by `$("input[name='foo']")`

Comment: I'm using PHP and also While Loop @GyroGearless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.num3', function(){
    var num1 = !isNaN(parseInt($('.num3').val())) ? parseInt($('.num3').val()) : 0;
    var num2 = !isNaN(parseInt($('.num1').val())) ? parseInt($('.num1').val()) : 0;
    var sub = num1 - num2;
    sub = sub < 0 ? 0 : sub;
    $('.num2').val( sub )
})

$(document).on('keyup', '.num1', function(){
    var num1 = !isNaN(parseInt($('.num3').val())) ? parseInt($('.num3').val()) : 0;
    var num2 = !isNaN(parseInt($('.num1').val())) ? parseInt($('.num1').val()) : 0;
    var sub = num1 - num2;
    sub = sub < 0 ? 0 : sub;
    $('.num2').val( sub )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='num2' class='num2' value='0' autocomplete='off' readonly  >

<input type='text' name='num3' class='num3' autocomplete='off'>

<input type='text' name='num1' class='num1' value="10">
```

Comment: Not working it's just saying NaN. I will only type 1 amount which is in num3 and num2 have already amount

Comment: @MonPadi updated my answer to consider blank input as 0

Comment: @MonPadi type a number greater than 10 ( in this example ) in the first imput to see the difference. A number less than 10 will lead to a negative sum and hence display 0

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple:

```
$(".num1").on("keyup", function() {
 var $this = $(this).parent().parent();
    var answer = $this.find('.num2').val() - $this.find('.num3').val();
    if(answer < 0)
    {
        $this.find('.num1').val(0);
    }
    else{
        $this.find('.num1').val(answer);
    }
});
```

Comment: Not working it's just saying NaN. I will only type 1 amount which is in num3 and num2 have already amount